# Styling list elements

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to add some style to each list's element which is located in some div. My haml code looks like this:

```
.some_container
  %ul
    %li= "1 element"
    %li= "2 element"
      %ul
        %li= "some content"
        %li= "some content"
    %li= "3 element"
```

I want to apply some style to each li in parent list but not to child lists. So I want to add style to %li with text ("1 element", "2 element", "3 element") and only to them. I have following sass style but it applied to each li element.

```
  .some_container ul li
    margin: 15px 10px 10px 5px
```

How to fix it. Thanks for all anserws and sorry for my english It isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1):

just restrict your rule to the first level using the child selector

```
.some_container > ul > li {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Of course it works. I don't know why I haven't checked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use direct child selector:

```
.some_container >  ul > li
```